# Java urlConnection, saving audio file to server?

Tags: java

I've seen examples with text files but is saving an audio file directly to a server done the same way with URLConnection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the same. Although make sure you use a binary output stream to write the content to disk.

Something like:

```
    URLConnection conn = new URL("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fd9e8761fad999a1bf1e095fc8f53ffe?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG")
            .openConnection();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/myfile");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int len;
    while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    outstream.close();
    is.close();
```

The example uses your gravatar, but same difference.

Comment: i won't have to use FTP correct, once file is done recording URLConnection class will save it directly to the server without a need for any special java server?

Comment: No you don't need a special server, something like the code above is all you need to save  the file to the same machine you run it from.